# Overfitting during last model training stage

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, overfitting, supervised-learning

To select, tune, train an ML model I used the following stages:

1. Split data in train / hold-out dataset
2. Perform nested cross validation using the train data only (loop with several models with a grid or randomsearch).
3. Get the top models from step 2 and perform a cross validation + hyperparameter optimization (still on the train data set only but not a nested CV this time)
4. Train the top models with the hyperparameter selected in step 3 on the whole train dataset
5. Assess the performance of the models after hyperparameter optimization (step 3) and training (step 4):

   1. On the whole train dataset
   2. On the hold-out dataset

Looking at the results, I usually get consistent results between step 2, 3 and 5.2 (e.g. RMSE ranges from few percent: -0.171277,-0.169008,-0.169454) that seems to validate the workflow.
However, there is a huge difference between the results from 5.1 and 5.2 (e.g. 0.038299 vs 0.171277) that indicate an overfitting.

Do I miss something ? How can I reduce overfitting at this stage ?

Comment: Usually, when using the nested cross-validation, your goal is to acquire an unbiased estimate of accuracy, by avoiding selecting one particular hold-out set for reporting the accuracy. So, the step that split your data into training and hold-out is not necessary. Secondly, the nested cross-validation lets you do hyperparameter model selection, so  Step 3, might need more consideration? I would recommend you to take a look at this paper where it explaines in detail the concept of nested cross-validation https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-7-91

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
From my understanding, several set of hyperparameters can be selected by the nested CV, so once the best models are chosen in stage 2, it is mandatory to repeat the inner procedure (i.e. CV + grid/random search) on the whole training set (see for example  'How Do You Configure the Final Model?' and response from Jason Brownlee November 27, 2020 at 6:37 am in  https://machinelearningmastery.com/nested-cross-validation-for-machine-learning-with-python/